# How to prove the the general equation of the family of circles through the intersection points of two circles?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $ \mathscr{C_{1}} $ and $ \mathscr C_{2} $ be two intersecting circles determined by the equations $$ x^2 + y^2 + A_{1}x + B_{1}y + C_{1} = 0 $$ and $$ x^2 + y^2 + A_{2}x + B_{2}y + C_{2} = 0. $$ For any number $ k≠−1 $, show that $$ x^2 + y^2 + A_{1}x + B_{1}y + C_{1} + k ( x^2 + y^2 + A_{2}x + B_{2}y + C_{2} ) = 0 $$ is the equation of a circle through the intersection points of $\mathscr{C_{1}}$ and $\mathscr C_{2}$. Show, conversely, that every such circle may be represented by such an equation for a suitable $ k $.



I'm stuck in this question, developing the given equation I could show that it assumes the form of 
$$ x^2 + y^2 + \frac{A_{1}+kA_{2}}{1+k}x + \frac{B_{1}+kB_{2}}{1+k}y + \frac{C_{1}+kC_{2}}{1+k} = 0 $$ 
which  proves that for $ k≠−1 $ the given equation is the equation of a circle. But I'm not entirely sure if it really proves that it is the equation of the family of circles through the intersection points of $ \mathscr{C_{1}} $ and $ \mathscr C_{2} $. I have no clue about how to prove the converse statement.

Comment: If a point is in the intersection then it satisfies both equations. If you have two true equations and multiply one by $k$ and add it to the other you get a new true equation. Therefore all those equations pass through the same pair of points. That shows one direction.

Comment: Indeed, any nonzero linear combination of the two equations will include those points as solutions.

Comment: Now assume that $A(x^2+y^2)+Cx+Dy+E=0$ is a circle passing through the intersection of the two given circles. By choosing $k=A-1$ we get another circle that passes through the two points and who's equation has the same quadratic part. The difference between the two equations is a linear equation. Since there is a single line passing through two points that equations should be equal to a multiple of the one you obtain by putting $k=-1$. Putting together the two linear combinations gives you the right $k$ to choose to the the original circle.

Comment: @Hellen, though I think I understood what you're saying in your first comment, even though I'm not sure why a multiple of a true equation is necessarily a true equation.

Comment: @amd this is an interesting take, can Hellen's second comment be considered a proof of it?

Comment: @nicholas80 Only indirectly. If $(x_0,y_0)$ is a solution to the equation $f(x,y)=0$, then $cf(x_0,y_0)=c\cdot0=0$, so $(x_0,y_0)$ is also a solution to the equation multiplied by some constant. (In addition, if $c\ne0$ you clearly neither add nor remove any solutions of the original equation, so the solution sets are identical.) Similarly, a common solution to a set of equations also satisfies a linear combination of them since all you’re doing is adding a bunch of zeros together to get zero again.

Answer (score 0):

Let the two points of the intersection be A and B and consider the straight line AB then, since the equation  $x^2 + y^2 + \frac{A_{1}+kA_{2}}{1+k}x + \frac{B_{1}+kB_{2}}{1+k}y + \frac{C_{1}+kC_{2}}{1+k} = 0$ is the equation of a circle of centre $(\frac{A_{1}+kA_{2}}{2(1+k)}, \frac{B_{1}+kB_{2}}{2(1+k)})$ pasing through the intersection points, you have to prove that the set of all those points for $k \in \mathbb{R} - \left\{1\right\}$ is a straight line except for a point (because since all the circles pass through the points, then it should be the bisection). Well, actually, we are forgetting the case $k = -1$ but check where is the centre.

Comment: Center is at $(\frac{A_{1}+kA_{2}}{2(1+k)}, \frac{B_{1}+kB_{2}}{2(1+k)})$.

Comment: oh, it´s true. I will change it. Thanks ^^

Comment: In this case I just have to prove that all points $ (\frac{A_{1}+kA_{2}}{2(1+k)}, \frac{B_{1}+kB_{2}}{2(1+k)}) $ are on a line and that it bisects the line segment $ \overline{I_{1}I_{2}} $ , right?

Comment: Yes, and check $k = -1$. Do you understand why?

Comment: @elescararriba for $ k=-1$ you get the equation of the line that passes through $\overline{I_{1}I_{2}}$.